# Using MYSQL transcations, basic questions

Tags: mysql, transactions

I am new to db programming. 
I read everywhere that I can use trasactions to rollback my actions if I encounter problem down the road.

I would like to know about transactions:

1. does a transaction "lock" the db ?
2. If a locking happens, what happens to other users accessing the db ? is it possible that they may get an error message ? Should I programatically check for such an error and try again ?

Are there things to do to make my db ready for transactions ? like setting the autocommit to off ? Is there anything else ?
Is there a downside to using transactions ? It seems all good to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole database is never locked, that would be very inefficient.
Rather, MySQL (depending on the storage engine), locks records and in some cases whole tables.

You need to make sure the storage engine is InnoDB, otherwise transactions are not possible.
Autocommit is a feature that exists in the connecting client only, it just issues a commit everytime you make changes to the DB.

Transactions will cause overhead and might cause significant performance problems. If you try to transactionally write to the same record (let's say a hit-counter on your homepage)  over and over again, then it locks this record and a lot of writes are blocked.

You should only use transactions if you need to provide consistency in your database, i.e. a bunch of records together should be written in 1 go, or not at all.

Answer (score 2):

1. No. They [allow queries to lock specific portions of the database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), and allow the database engine to present a uniform view of the data to other clients even on tables that are being updated.
2. They see the data as it was before the relevant query happened, and they may be prevented from writing to the table.

Not all table engines support transactions so you will need to use one that does (such as InnoDB), and transactions do take a non-zero amount of time to process.

Comment: What they see actually depends on the isolation-level, but as a simplification, your answer is completely correct. +1

Answer (score 1):

1. The simple answer is Yes.
2. The waiting query will wait till the table is not locked and then execute.

You should know that according to the db engine you are using, which is MyISAM by default, the locking is table-wise. There are different engines like InnoDB that do Row-Locking.

Also, there is a number of queries that can execute simultaneously even if they are all on different tables. If you exceed this number, you will also receive a lock. You can check out in the phpmyadmin how many locks you received to find out if there are problems in your db handling.

Regarding transactions: sometimes you do wish to update the db with parts of the information. It really depends on your usage.

Comment: MyISAM does not support transaction, and table-level and row-level locks are not exactly the transaction locking, they are the locking mecahnism implemented in the storage engine.

Answer (score 1):

Ans 1. No. It locks parts of tables or complete tables depending on the nature of the queries. These locaks can be read or write locks.
Ans 2. If the user wants to lock a part of a table that another user has a write lock, the user is held up until the lock becomes free. If the other user has a read lock and the user wants a write lock the user is held up until the lock becomes free. You need to read up about deadlocks.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are talking about MySQL and transactions, the whole answer is about InnoDB, although the most of it is valid for any storage engine, supporting transactions.

The locking in transaction depends on storage engine and on [transaction isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29). MySQL/InnoDB uses row-versioning for implementing transactions, and lower the number of locks used in all isolation level, except for serializable. The default isolation level in MySQL is repeatable read.

Generally updates use write-locks, which means that another transaction cannot update the same row, but can read it. If you try to access a row that is locked, MySQL will wait until lock-wait timeout is reached, then will kill the query, informing you that the lock-wait timeout is reached. Usually this should not happen. The most danger part in using transactions however, is introducing `dead-locks` - when `transaction A` updates `record1` and tries to update `record2`, which is locked by `transaction B` - `transaction B` have updated `record2` and tries to update `record1`, but `record1` is locked by `A`, so both waits for each other.

General advice is to keep your transactions as small as possible, and lock the rows you are going to update as early as possible, to prevent deadlock (you can use select... for update for this).

A lot of information can be found in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) and in the MySQL Certification guide.